# Setting a background in ionic not working

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I am trying to set a background image in ionic for my main page and having some problems this is my code:

On my home.page.scss:

```css
ion-content {
    --background: url(src/assets/images/finalbackground.jpg);
    --background-repeat: no-repeat;
    --background-position: center
    --background-size: contain;
}
```

On my home.page.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="home.page" href="home.page.css">
    <ion-content padding class="photo"></ion-content>
```

The image should look like this:

[image: Final background image what it should look like]

What it's appearing as in ionic lab:

[image: Ionic Lab preview plain screen]

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Remove all `--` for your **CSS** property. It should be `background-image: url(...);` not `--background-image: url(...);`.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I've removed the -- but still not having a luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to background none because if any background setting is exist it's reset. Use code like this.

```
    ion-content{
      --background: none;
      background-image: url('');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center top;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding></ion-content>
```

**home.scss**

```
ion-content {
    --background: url(../../assets/image/bg4.png) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```